# How to solve RegistryBuilder issue in Junit test for Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, junit

I have created a test in Juni and add in to Maven project when i am building project following error is coming

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/RegistryBuilder
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:57)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.getDefaultHttpClientFactory(ApacheHttpClient.java:250)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient$Factory.(ApacheHttpClient.java:227)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.(HttpCommandExecutor.java:70)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.java:40)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sap.drools.controller.Resource.openCheckoutPage(Resource.java:18)
>     at
>   com.sap.drools.controller.TestExpressMode.ExpressModeFileUploadTest(TestExpressMode.java:11)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 36 more

How I can solve this issue and execute junit test in Maven project smoothly?

Thanks

Comment: could you provide more detail on test which you are trying to execute and the project structure ?

Answer (score 0):

by adding depedencies in pom

org.apache.httpcomponents
    httpcore
    4.4
    test

org.apache.httpcomponents
  httpclient
  4.5.2

org.apache.httpcomponents
            httpmime
            4.5.2